How do I `include` custom headers which is inside `includes/` inside `functions/create_note.c`
So this is my source tree for a simple note-taking app I'm creating.
Folder PATH listing for volume Seagate Ext
Volume serial number is 6C91-D326
E:.
ª   .gitignore
ª   README.md
ª   
+---.vscode
ª       c_cpp_properties.json
ª       settings.json
ª       
+---src
    ª   compile.sh
    ª   main.c
    ª   note-taker.config
    ª   
    +---functions
    ª       create_note.c
    ª       delete_note.c
    ª       view_note.c
    ª       
    +---includes
            foo.c
            foo.h
            func.h

Whenever I run gcc main.c includes/foo.c functions/create_note.c functions/view_note.c functions/delete_note.c -o x I'm getting:
functions/create_note.c:7:10: fatal error: includes/foo.h: No such file or directory
 #include "includes/foo.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
functions/view_note.c:3:10: fatal error: includes/func.h: No such file or directory
 #include "includes/func.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
functions/delete_note.c:3:10: fatal error: includes/func.h: No such file or directory
 #include "includes/func.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Inside my create_note.c this is how I've ordered the preprocessors.
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "includes/foo.h"
#include "includes/func.h"

func.h has three functions declared which are all inside functions/, and create_note.c is one of them. The above shows how the preprocessors are inside create_note.c as mentioned. How would I solve the compile error?
I've tried doing this in my #include:

#include "src\include\foo.h"
#include "./includes/foo.h

Expectation is: the program should compile successfully and work!

Welcome to SO. Have you tried telling your compiler to look in your main folder? If you provide src as include folder (in gcc you can do this with -I option, then you can just use relative path from there in your files. Or is there any reason not to use that option?

Initially I tried -I and did #include "foo.h" without adding the includes/. Later on I saw below that we have to add includes/ and it worked!!

In the end, it is rather simple: If you combine the folder from -I option with the name you add to #include directive must result in the correct path. You can split the path in multiple ways as long as the result is correct after concatenating.

Understood! Once again thank you

You have two options to solve this.
OPTION 1:
assuming you current working directory is src add the -I includes/ flag to gcc this will tell gcc to look for headers in the includes/ directory
then you will have to include like this  #include "func.h" instead of this #include "includes/func.h"
if you want to include it like #include "includes/func.h" add -I . flag instead
Here is how the full command would be
gcc main.c includes/foo.c functions/create_note.c functions/view_note.c functions/delete_note.c -I . -o x 

OPTIONS 2:
prefix your include headers with ../
.. means previous dir so to include includes/func.h from functions/create_note.c include this way
#include "../includes/func.h"

WHY YOUR CODE DIDN'T GIVE YOU THE EXPECTED RESULT:
when you type #include "src\include\foo.h" the compiler actually search for the header file in E:\src\functions\src\include which doesn't exist
it searches for it relatively to create_note.c
#include "./includes/foo.h" didn't work for the same reason the only diffrence it was looking in a different directory in this case it was E:\src\functions\includes.

Thank you very much @ammar !
I did #include "includes/foo.h" and then used the -I. ` flag and it worked stupendously. Thank you very much!!
I tried upvoting the answer, but I'm getting you need the 15 reputation to upvote. I'll get it and upvote

Note what What are the benefits of a relative path such as ../include/header.h for a header?.  Note that the question is about using ../ in the relative path.  Names like <sys/types.h without a ../ are OK.  In general, you should avoid paths with the ../ notation.  Use -I /some/directory/include if you use #include "header.h" or use -I /some/directory if you use #include "include/header.h".  Be consistent in how you include files within your project.

Heard that loud and clear @JonathanLeffler !!
